# UpdateView not saving changes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

my UpdateView is not saving the new changes and showing no errors

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
type_ch = [('credit','credit'),('game','game')]
currency_ch = [('€','€'),('$','$'),('DZD','DZD'),('Unit','Unit')]
distributor = models.ForeignKey(Distributor,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=False)
model = models.CharField(choices=type_ch,max_length=20,null=True,blank=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=False)
price = models.FloatField(default=0.00)
currency = models.CharField(choices=currency_ch,max_length=20,null=True,blank=False)
available = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=False)
note = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(default='defser.png')
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta():
    model = Service
    fields = ['distributor','model','name','price','currency','available','note','image']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['model'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control-account'
    self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control-account'
    self.fields['distributor'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control-account'
    self.fields['price'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control-account'
    self.fields['currency'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control-account'
    self.fields['available'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control-account'
    self.fields['note'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control-account'
```

views.py

```
class ServiceUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = Service
template = "app/service_form"
form_class  = ServiceForm
```

service_form.html

```
 <form class="needs-validation" action="." method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {% csrf_token %} 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Distributor: <small class="text-muted"> (select your own distributor accountt)</small></label>
                {{ form.distributor}}
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Type:</label>
                {{form.model}}
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Service Name:</label>
              {{form.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Service Currency:</label>
                {{form.currency}}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Amount Available:</label>
                {{form.available}}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Price For Unit: DZD</label>
                {{form.price}}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Note:</label>
                {{form.note}}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Service Image</label>
                {{form.image}}
              </div>
              <hr>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

i'm trying to allow the user to be able to change all the values of the saved service
but when i press the submit button it redirects me back to previous page an nothing changes on the Service values

please help me guys

Comment: it is not class Meta(): change to class Meta:

Comment: thanks but still same issue